# Wipe a hard drive that won't boot from a USB? or delete and move partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, reinstall

I have an older Aspire E1-470P. It was getting old and slow so I installed Ubuntu as a dual boot.  It worked for a while and then after a windows update it got stuck in update hell.  Despite my best efforts, I can only get into Ubuntu, and the PC won't boot from USB (Secure Boot on?)

I bit the bullet and bought a new PC.

I would like to wipe the hard drive and make it a dedicated Ubuntu machine, music and video server. However  I cannot use Ubuntu Live USB to reinstall.  I could feasibly wipe the Windows partitions with Gparted, but I don't think I can shift the Ubuntu partition to the left without booting from external media.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you have `grub` working, it can be configured to boot an ISO meaning you can have your ISO on your hdd/sdd, and boot it for 'live' or install purposes.  I've done it before, but not recently.  This may be helpful - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot and report back and mark your post as the answer if it works.

Comment: You really should keep Windows, as you'll need it to do things like BIOS updates, etc. Make it a dual-boot configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the caveat.  I am sure the drive is corrupt but I can get into BIOS when I need to.   I just can't boot from any external media.   What partitions do I need to keep?

Comment: Keep all the current partitions. Use Windows Disk Management app to reduce the ntfs partition to make room for Ubuntu, or let the Ubuntu installer do it for you.

Comment: Thanks all.  I used Guiverc’s solution (specifically grml-rescueboot).  The pc was already a dual boot, but Windows was non functional and I already had a new Windows PC (also a dual boot). In addition I can access BIOS menu from GRUB if required, and don’t foresee needing windows on it anymore.